# Need help understand a yocto error for a new recipe

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

i am new to Yocto and trying to write a new recipe. i wrote a new recipe myrecipe_git.bb, and not able to understand what i might be doing wrong here. The error logs are

```
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: Running task 7614 of 12909 (/opt/workspace/TestPackage/recipesdir/abc/myrecipe_git.bb:do_package)
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: recipe myrecipe-r0: task do_package: Started
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: Running task 7806 of 12909 (/opt/workspace/TestPackage/morerecipes/setup/otherrecipe.bb:do_prepare_recipe_sysroot)
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: recipe otherrecipe-1.0-r0: task do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Started
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: recipe myrecipe-r0: task do_package: Succeeded
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: Running task 7961 of 12909 (/opt/workspace/TestPackage/recipesdir/avs-cpp-sdk/myrecipe_git.bb:do_packagedata)
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: recipe myrecipe-r0: task do_packagedata: Started
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: recipe myrecipe-r0: task do_packagedata: Succeeded
[buildfarm-ssh] ERROR: otherrecipe-1.0-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Manifest /opt/workspace/TestPackage/build/tmp/sstate-control/manifest-x86_64_x86_64-nativesdk-myrecipe.populate_sysroot not found in simulator core2-64 x86_64 allarch x86_64_x86_64-nativesdk (variant '')?
[buildfarm-ssh] ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/workspace/TestPackage/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/otherrecipe/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.95405
NOTE: recipe otherrecipe-1.0-r0: task do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Failed
[buildfarm-ssh] recipesdirERROR: Task (/opt/workspace/TestPackage/morerecipes/setup/otherrecipe.bb:do_prepare_recipe_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'
[buildfarm-ssh] NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 8366 tasks of which 8336 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
[buildfarm-ssh]
Summary: 1 task failed:
  /opt/workspace/TestPackage/morerecipes/setup/otherrecipe.bb:do_prepare_recipe_sysroot
Summary: There were 139 WARNING messages.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

my recipe looks like

```
SUMMARY = "My Recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "My Recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

MIRRORS = ""
PREMIRRORS = ""

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"

SRC_URI = "git://git.xxxx;protocol=ssh;branch=mainline;"
SRCREV = "yyy...ccc"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

ALLOW_EMPTY:${PN} = "1"
```

Looking for any feedback/advice on what i might be doing wrong here. Thanks in advance

----update---
the otherrecipe.bb file is something like this

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""
DEPENDS= "setup ..."
RDEPENDS:${PN} += "framework packages"

require common-variables.inc

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/common/app"

inherit pkgconfig cmake ptest framework systemd

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DYOCTO_TARGET_MACHINE=${MACHINE}"

PACKAGECONFIG ??= "..."
PACKAGECONFIG[tests] = "-DBUILD_TESTS=ON,-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF,googletest,"


FILES:${PN} += "\
    ${datadir}/setup/assets/* \
    ${libdir}/*.so \
    "
FILES:${PN}-dev = "${includedir}"
FILES:${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/pkgconfig"
FILES:${PN}-dbg = "${datadir}/lib/.debug/*.so"

do_set_assets() {
    if [ -d "${S}/assets-${MACHINE}/" ]; then
        cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/assets ${S}/assets_copy
        cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/assets-${MACHINE}/* ${S}/assets/
    fi
}

do_reset_assets() {
    if [ -d "${S}/assets-${MACHINE}/" ]; then
        rm -r ${S}/assets
        mv ${S}/assets_copy ${S}/assets
    fi
}

do_install:append() {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/setup
    cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/assets ${D}${datadir}/setup
    if [ -d "${S}/assets-${MACHINE}/" ]; then
        cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/assets-${MACHINE}/* ${D}${datadir}/setup/assets/
    fi
    chmod -R 0777 ${D}${datadir}/setup
}

addtask set_assets after do_configure before do_compile

do_set_assets[nostamp] = "1"

addtask reset_assets after do_install before do_package

do_reset_assets[nostamp] = "1"
```

Comment: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/tasks.html?highlight=do_prepare_recipe_sysroot#do-prepare-recipe-sysroot
missings contents in DEPENDS macro ?